# Unable to scrape something hidden by `aria-hidden` using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape my own Linkedin profile's (if you switch on Creator mode) Analytics. Under which there's a section named "Top Demographics".  I'm using Python and Selenium to gather the data.

**Problem:** See image below. Unfortunately I'm unable to share the HTML body since it frequently changes.
[image: Linkedin Analytics Image]

I tried to use Selenium to capture the `Locations` and click on it to scrape the data however I'm unable to get the HTML structure to understand what shall I catch it with.

> This is the first iteration of question and if my query is not clear, please allow me clarify it by posting comments - so that I can explain if I've missed something.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML and your code trials.